# Can I integrate Algolia with Firebase Realtime Database for index search

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I am looking at using algolia to perform index search in my app using firebase. Now from what I see I have to be running on Cloud Firestore for algolia to work, which means migrating ie. my "Users" node to Cloud Firestore?
Or am i wrong? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use Algolia with the realtime database. Firebase actually has a sample cloud function that allows that. You can find it [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fulltext-search)

Comment: Thanks, will work with the link you provided.